# Set and Get a Button id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to get a piece of functionality working before implementing it into a website I am building.

Now the idea is when a button within the index.php page is pressed the test.php page is filtered based upon the button id (TableID), which has been stored. The button id stored should then be passed via php session to the test.php page, where the mysql query within the test.php gets the passed button id (TableID). The test.php page is then filtered accordingly.

**Example:**

1) User click ths test button

2) The button id stored is passed to a $_Session

3) The user is then redirected to the test.php

4) Within the test.php page the page is filtered based on the button id stored

So the test.php page image below if test Test 2 button was pressed would display the following:

- Test 2
- Test 2 Holder - if this isn't being displayed then their is an error.

database

[image: enter image descrion here]

**

it  index.php

**

[image]

Code So far

```
<?php 

    session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="full" lang="en">
<!-- Make sure the <html> tag is set to the .full CSS class. Change the background image in the full.css file. -->

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Index Page </title>

     <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/images.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/text.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <?php 

        include("php/connection.php");

    ?>

    <div class="container">

        <br/>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 align="center">Page Title</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <BR/>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <div class="row">

                    <?php

                        $data = mysql_query("   SELECT *
                                                FROM tableTest

                                              ") or die(mysql_error());

                                    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 

                                    {  

                                        echo "<div class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3\">\n";
                                            echo "   <div class=\"thumbnail well\">\n";
                                            echo "        <div class=\"thumbnail-pad\">\n";

                                            echo "           <br/>\n";

                                            echo "           <h4 align=\"center\">\n" . $info['testName'] . "</h4>\n";

                                            echo "           <br/>\n";

                                            echo "           <div align=\"center\"> <a href=\"test.php\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-md\" type=\"submit\">View League</a> </div>\n";

                                            echo "         </div>\n";
                                            echo "    </div>\n";
                                        echo " </div>\n";

                                    }
                                ?>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container-->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**

- test.php

**

- Test Page Image

[image]

Code

```
<?php
    // start session
    session_start(); 

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="full" lang="en">
<!-- Make sure the <html> tag is set to the .full CSS class. Change the background image in the full.css file. -->

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Test Page</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/images.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/text.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <?php 

      include_once("php/connection.php");

    ?>

    <div class="container">    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <?php include_once("sideNav.php");?>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-12" style="width: 0 auto;">


          <div class="section1 well">
            <div class="row">

            <?php

            $data = mysql_query(" SELECT testName , testBio                                                 
            FROM tableTest
            WHERE tableID = 1
            GROUP BY tableID ") 
            or die(mysql_error());

            $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );

            echo "<div class=\"col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12\">\n";
            echo "   <h2 align=\"center\">" .$info['testName'] . "</h2>\n";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div class=\"col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12\">\n";
            echo "<h5 align=\"center\"> Drescription </h5>\n";
            echo "<p align=\"center\">" . $info['testBio'] . "</p>\n";
            echo "</div>\n";     


            ?>

            <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">
            <a href="index.php" align="center" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Go Back </a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>  

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

     <?php include_once("footer.php");?>


    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript or jquery code?  It's tagged with those so I assumed there would be some....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the "Button ID" of each button in a hidden input in the same form as the button.

```
echo "<form action=\"test.php\" method=\"POST\"><div class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3\">\n";
echo "<div class=\"thumbnail well\">\n";
echo "<div class=\"thumbnail-pad\">\n";
echo "<br/>\n";
echo "<h4 align=\"center\">\n" . $info['testName'] . "</h4>\n";
echo "<br/>\n";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$info['tableID']."'>";
echo "<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-md\" type=\"submit\" value=\"View League\"></div>\n";
echo "</div>\n";
echo "</div>\n";
echo "</div></form>\n";
```

You need to use the FORM tags so the server knows what data you're passing to it. In this case, it will pass the hidden id with value = $info['tableID'] to it, depending on which button you press.

```
    $data = mysql_query(" SELECT testName , testBio FROM tableTest 
WHERE tableID = ".$_POST['tableID']." GROUP BY tableID ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Hopefully that should help. Just remember, when taking input from a webpage, you NEED to be using forms.

Comment: hidden fields can be vary helpful however be sure that whatever you are putting in them is not something that needs to be kept from everyone seeing

Comment: all you need to do to see a hidden field is view the HTML source code

Comment: Agreed, always be careful what you show your users.

Comment: Thank all ! But I have an additional question. Do I just add the bottom piece of code into the test.php? Also I am getting error around the Group By not being seen as mysql within php.

Comment: The bottom piece of code is YOUR code with a slight modification. Just replace `$data =` with the code I added.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have added the code to files, however, no TableID is being passed?

Comment: Do you know how to use Web Developer Tools in Firefox or Chrome? Also watch your case. `T != t`

Comment: Ok, last comment (gotta go soon) but try performing a request, have the developer tools open and check your Network->Params settings. See what is being passed (if anything) to the server. Also, do some research on forms and post requests.